# Resizing marginfigure to the side of a margin?

Tags: margins, resize, leftmargin

I want to resize a marginfigure in twoside margin

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{caesar_book} 
% -- use dummy graphics
\usepackage{mwe} 
%auto generate the bib file
\usepackage{filecontents} 
% -- language: English -- 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% -- biblatex --
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic]{biblatex} % xxx
% the .bib file with the references
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section*{Scaling a marginfigure in the direction of a marginside}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\blindtext[2]
\newpage
\blindtext[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

The problem appears when the marginfigure is on the left margin.

[image]

Resizing a figure on the left margin results a figure and a text overlap.

Comment: Have you tried `width=\textwidth`? If you choose something larger it is not too surprising that something would overlap with other bits of the page eventually.

Comment: If you really need to have figures larger than the `\textwidth` you could use `\hspace*{-0.2\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}` for the second figure.

Comment: @marmot: Yes! That solves my problem. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\mfincludegraphics` command for inserting oversized pictures; the excess will be *automatically* moved in the direction of the outer margin. You don't need to know what page the picture will be typeset on.

This may require multiple runs of LaTeX to stabilize.

In the code below I added two blank pages so one figure falls in a left-hand page and one in a right-hand page, to see the difference.

```latex
\documentclass{caesar_book} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{refcount}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{mfig}
\newcommand{\mfincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{mfig}\label{\themfig}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][\ifodd\getpagerefnumber{\themfig}l\else r\fi]{%
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\mbox{}\newpage

\section*{Scaling a marginfigure in the direction of a marginside}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
    \mfincludegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle-A}}
\end{marginfigure}

\blindtext[2]
\newpage
\blindtext[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
    \mfincludegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle-B}}
\end{marginfigure}

\blindtext[2]

\newpage\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could just make `\marginparwidth` larger and achieve the same effect without all the overfull `\hbox` warnings.

```
\documentclass{caesar_book} 
% -- use dummy graphics
\usepackage{mwe} 
%auto generate the bib file
\usepackage{filecontents} 
% -- language: English -- 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% -- biblatex --
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-classic]{biblatex} % xxx
% the .bib file with the references
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2\marginparwidth}
% to center marginpar in margin given \marginparsep
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{\dimexpr \paperwidth-\textwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-2\marginparsep}

\begin{document}
\section*{Scaling a marginfigure in the direction of a marginside}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\blindtext[2]
\newpage
\blindtext[1]
\begin{marginfigure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \caption{A small rectangle put in the margin.\label{rectangle}}%
\end{marginfigure}%
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```